# Apache Flink - how to stop and resume stream processing on downstream failure

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink application that consumes incoming messages on a Kafka topic with multiple partitions, does some processing then sends them to a sink that sends them over HTTP to an external service. Sometimes the downstream service is down the stream processing needs to stop until it is back in action.

There are two approaches I am considering.

1. Throw an exception when the Http sink fails to send the output message. This will cause the task and job to restart according to the configured restart strategy. Eventually the downstream service will be back and the system will continue where it left off.
2. Have the Sink sleep and retry on failure; it can do this continually until the downstream service is back.

From what I understand and from my PoC, with 1. I will lose exactly-least once guarantees since the sink itself is external state. As far as I can see, you cannot make a simple HTTP endpoint transactional, as it needs to be to implement TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction.

With 2. this is less of an issue since pipeline will not proceed until the sink makes a successful write, and I can rely on back pressure throughout the system to pause the retrieval of messages from the Kafka source.

The main questions I have are:

1. Is it a correct assumption that you can't make a TwoPhaseCommitSinkFunction for a simple HTTP endpoint?
2. Which of the two strategies, or neither, makes the most sense?
3. Am I missing simpler obvious solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try AsyncIO in Flink - https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/operators/asyncio/.

Try to make the HTTP endpoint send a response once all operation has been done for the request, e.g. In http server, the process for the request has been done and the result has been committed to DB. Then use a http async client in AsyncIO operator. The AsyncIO operator will *wait* until the response is received by the operator. If any error happened, the Flink streaming pipeline will fail and restart the pipeline based on recovery strategy.

All requests to HTTP endpoint without receiving response will be in the internal buffer of AsyncIO operator, and once streaming pipeline failed, the requests pending in the buffer will be saved in the checkpoint state. It will also trigger back pressure when the internal buffer is full.

Comment: I was attached to the idea of doing this with a sink but this seems like a good way to go, thanks

Comment: Have accepted this answer. The only acceptable alternative I found was to manage a queue of HTTP requests using the internal state of a sink, send them with a thread pool over time, but the async operator seems equivalent but ready made.

Comment: That's async operator for :)